# How to extract string (date) from log file

Tags: string, date, logging, grep, extract

i have log that not usual

```
Jan  5 11:34:00 log messages here
Jan 13 16:21:00 log messages here
```

i try

```
grep -oE '[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}'
```

the result if i combine with **tail -n 1** is

```
16:21:00
```

expected output

```
Jan 13 16:21:00
```

how can i achieve that ? i'm confused about regex.. or there is another better approach ?

the interisting part is my log have appended space not zero in date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example I might would do this: `.*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}`. Just matching anything before the time since that also needed.

Or make it more precise with the assumption that the month is always 3 character long:
`^[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+\d{1,2}\s+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}`.

Comment: Anytime my friend.

Comment: and may i ask one question again ?
what if the log has.. more string after the time
so like
 
Jan   3 11:43:50 String1 string[123]: log message here

it can be precisely like that ?

Comment: Well that should not cause any problem to match the 'Jan 3 11:43:50' part which you are interested in. Or at least I dont see any problem.

Comment: nope, the first solution you gift is absolutely fine and save the day..
it's just.. in case want to be more precisely..

btw, the second solutions is not showing anything.. but its no problem cause the first one fix it..

thanks

Comment: Hmm strange. It works on here: https://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp. And you are welcome.

Comment: @RenaldiYulvianda, Could you please do check once my solution too if that helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, this will match exact string till timings only.

```
grep -ioP "(^[a-zA-Z]+\D*\d+\D*(\d+:){2}\d+)"  Input_file
```